# Java - Runtime.xmemory()

Tags: java, memory, runtime, byte

What does

```
Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
```

and

```
.freeMemory();
```

return?
I get some strane values on my 4 GB ram laptop.Is it mbytes bytes or kbytes?

I need to do have a slider splitted into 512MBs but having numbers each 1024MBs

Thats my loop

```
        ram = new JSlider();
    ram.setMinimum(512);
    ram.setPaintTicks(true);
    ram.setMajorTickSpacing(512);
    ram.setValue(512);
    ram.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(750, 50));
    ram.setVisible(true);
    Hashtable<Integer, JLabel> labelTable = new Hashtable<Integer, JLabel>();
    int mbs = 1024;
    while(mbs <= Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()/1024){       
        labelTable.put(mbs, new JLabel(Integer.toString(mbs)));
        mbs += 1024;
    }
    ram.setLabelTable(labelTable);
    ram.setPaintLabels(true);

        frame.add(ram)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#freeMemory%28%29)

[`freeMemory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#freeMemory%28%29)

> public long freeMemory() 
> Returns the amount of free memory
>   in the Java Virtual Machine. Calling the gc method may result in
>   increasing the value returned by freeMemory. 
> Returns: an approximation
>   to the total amount of memory currently available for future allocated
>   objects, measured in **bytes**.

[`maxMemory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#maxMemory%28%29)

> public long maxMemory()
>  Returns the maximum amount of memory
>   that the Java virtual machine will attempt to use. If there is no
>   inherent limit then the value Long.MAX_VALUE will be returned.
>   Returns: the maximum amount of memory that the virtual machine will
>   attempt to use, measured in **bytes**

(Sorry, this wasn't going to fit in a comment)

Comment: Well , yeah the fact is that I have a loop doing stuff for each half gig of memory. I cant get it to work with the free memory

Comment: The biggest problem I can think of is that `freeMemory` won't be the same each time you check it.  So as you put more things into your map, the `freeMemory` will reduce...not sure if that is by design or not...1024 is a kb...just to be sure...

Answer (score 0):

The javadoc states that the values will be in bytes.

> an approximation to the total amount of memory currentlyavailable for future allocated objects, measured in bytes.